# Python not finding packages installed via PIP

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, python-module

scoured many examples but couldn't find anything steps that resolved my issue. Python can't seem to find any package I install via PIP. For example:

```
tims-MacBook-Pro:~ timlindsey$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

however when I then go into python and try to import numpy

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

It appears to happen no matter what package I try to bring in via pip. I'll spare the text dump but numpy is indeed there in 
pip list

it seems to be looking at the same python install:

```
tims-MacBook-Pro:~ timlindsey$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
tims-MacBook-Pro:~ timlindsey$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

here is my .bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="Users/timlindsey/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

I don't know where to go from here, any ideas?

Comment: export PATH="Users/timlindsey/anaconda/bin:$PATH"  should be export PATH="/Users/timlindsey/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

Comment: ^ Yep, you're missing the `/`...

Comment: yes that did the trick. can one of you post this as the answer? also could you give a quick snip about why this worked? does python examine path when invoked?